# 2 multiselect checkbox dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have 2 multiselect dropdown in which the option of 2nd dropdown depends on the selected value of 1st dropdown. It works if i remove multiselect plugin but if i add multiselect plugin it stops working.

Script:

```
$(function(){

var $cat = $("#category1"),
    $subcat = $("#category2");

$cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    $('#category2').multiselect('rebuild');
});
$('#category1').multiselect();
$('#category2').multiselect({

    includeSelectAllOption: true

});


});
```

here is the fiddle with multiselect(this is not working when i select value from 1st multiselect):
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pL4hg76b/66/)

Code without multiselect this is working: [JSFIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pL4hg76b/67/)

Comment: code is not working in single selection as well !

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution yes but if you remove the multiselect from jquery and multiple tag from html, the code will work

Comment: bootstrap multiselect provide only enable or disabled option not hide and show.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution So is there any other way to do this

Comment: you need to generate second dropdown dynamically instead of hide/show it.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?